# How to inject kubernetes secret into configuration file

Tags: kubernetes

I have one configuration file which as following. This file is a configmap and will be mounted and read by my app. The problem here is that this configuration file has one property with my db password. And I don't want to it to be exposed. So is there anyway to inject kubernetes secret into such configuration file. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>my_db_password</value>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of an init container an a shared volume for this, if you don't want to expose the secret to the application container directly.

The init container uses the secret to create the configuration file from a template (f.e. `sed` replacing a placeholder) and place the file in a shared volume. The application container uses the volume to retrieve the file. (Given that you can configure the path where the application expects the configuration file.)

The other option is to simply use the secret as an environment variable for your application and retrieve it separately from the general configuration.

Answer (score 0):

try below steps

```
1.  add the password as an environment variable

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>${my_db_password}</value>
  </property>

2. include the password in secret object
3. load the env variable from secret object. you need to define env from secret object ref in pod definition
```

Comment: What causes the environment variable reference to be expanded?

Comment: there are multiple ways. you can try using envsubst < filename

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that XML will not expand that variable. Not sure if it fits your use case but we had a JVM application with some XML configuration and did the following in order to make it work:

1. Create `Secret`
2. Reference `Secret` in the `Depoyment` environment variables
3. Inject them as `System Properties` in a `JAVA_OPT` variable
4. System properties get expanded

Example

Deployment file:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myimage
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: my-secret-credentials
                  key: user
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: my-secret-credentials
                  key: password
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-db.user=$(DB_USER) -Ddb.password=$(DB_PASSWORD)"
```

Your XML config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>"#{systemProperties['db.user']}"</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>"#{systemProperties['db.password']}"</value>
  </property>
```

This way your secret gets injected safely. Just pay attention when referencing environment variables from another environment variable in the deployment yaml, it uses parenthesis instead of curly braces.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this approach is working on Hadoop 2.

In Hadoop 3+ I used the following configuration for core-site.xml and hive-metastore.xml to set the config values from environment variables:

core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>${env.HADOOP_DEFAULT_FS}</value>
</property>
```

metastore-site.xml:

```
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>${env.METASTORE_PASSWORD}</value>
   </property>
```

Where HADOOP_DEFAULT_FS and METASTORE_PASSWORD are defined into a k8s secret which is attached to the container as env variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tried to solve the same problem.
I tried to avoid `sed`, `eval` or any other solution that is not secure (special chars or similar issue).

Create a secret that contains a config file (in your case it will be xml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  config.yaml: |
    apiUrl: "https://my.api.com/api/v1"
    username: <user>
    password: <password>
```

and then mount the secret as file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
      optional: false # default setting; "mysecret" must exist
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-config-file/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod